# Calculating handling time out of overlapping intervals

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, intervals, overlap

I have a raw data exported and transformed a bit from salesforce below;

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['contact_start','name', 'aht'], 
                  data=[['2021-09-27 09:58:00','Venus','180'],
                        ['2021-09-27 10:00:00','Venus','240'],
                        ['2021-09-27 11:05:00','Venus','60'],
                        ['2021-09-27 10:55:00','Mars','30'],
                        ['2021-09-27 10:56:00','Mars','30']])
```

[image: original data]

using these codes below

```
df["contact_start"] = pd.to_datetime(df["contact_start"], format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S",errors='coerce')
df["date"] = df["contact_start"].dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
df['aht']=pd.to_datetime(df["aht"], unit='s').dt.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
df['contact_finish'] = pd.to_timedelta(df['aht']) + pd.to_datetime(df['contact_start'])
df['contact_finish'] = df['contact_finish'].astype('datetime64[s]')
```

I transform this into :

[image: transform]

but my final goal is to deal with overlapping and I ran out of ideas how to make it happen.

the outcome should be like this in below:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['date','name', 'total_duration_sec'], 
                  data=[['2021-09-27','Venus','420'], 
                        ['2021-09-27','Mars','60']])
```

[image: outcome]

I guess it looks simple but in fact it is really not. I would appreciate any help.

Edit : I do not know how to put a more meaningful data in python so i uploaded a sample data file (3kb csv)

[sample data](https://wetransfer.com/downloads/35e97d9676fc0ef1280217cc92c5987420211022120534/817599)

Comment: Is it 420 seconds or 4020 seconds for Venus?

Comment: she has 180 seconds from the first one and since the second one started after the first one, the remaining duration from second one is also 180(3 mins), and last one has 60 seconds(1 min) total of 420 seconds (7 mins)

Answer (score 0):

I think you could create a time difference in seconds between successive contact_start per name

```
upper_seconds = (
    df.sort_values(['name','contact_start'])
      .groupby('name')['contact_start'].diff(-1)
      .dt.total_seconds().abs())

print(upper_seconds.sort_index())
# 0     120.0
# 1    3900.0
# 2       NaN
# 3      60.0
# 4       NaN
# Name: contact_start, dtype: float64
```

Now you can use this as a upper clip on aht then groupby name and date and sum.

```
res = (
    df['aht'].astype(int)
      .clip(upper=upper_seconds)
      .groupby([df['name'], df['date']]).sum()
      .reset_index(name='total_duration_sec')
)
print(res)
    name        date  total_duration_sec
0   Mars  2021-09-27                  60
1  Venus  2021-09-27                 420
```

Note that I used first two lines you already wrote to have the good type.

```
df["contact_start"] = pd.to_datetime(df["contact_start"], 
                                     format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S",errors='coerce')
df["date"] = df["contact_start"].dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
```

Comment: Somehow it seems working when there is no overlapping, but with bigger data it does not work unfortunately, I added a sample data in first post if you wish to check it out.

Answer (score 0):

You can make your existing code work by adding these lines to your code:

```
overlapped = pd.Series(df.groupby(['name']).apply(lambda x: (x['contact_finish'] - x['contact_start'].shift(-1)).dt.total_seconds().shift()).droplevel(0), name='overlapped')
overlapped = overlapped.mask(overlapped<0, 0).fillna(0)

df['date'] = df['contact_start'].dt.date
df = df.groupby(['date', 'name']).apply(lambda x: (((x['contact_finish'] - x['contact_start']).dt.seconds) - overlapped).sum()).reset_index(name='total_duration_sec')
```

OUTPUT:

```
         date   name  total_duration_sec
0  2021-09-27   Mars                60.0
1  2021-09-27  Venus               420.0
```

Comment: Hi Muhammad, it seems working with the sample data of two lines but my actual data is 79152 rows and df is giving me negative results in total_duration_sec

Comment: Can you please post some larger chunk of data or the chunk that gives problematic results

Comment: I edited the first post, thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is a solution involving [step functions](https://staircase.dev) which can handle overlaps over day boundaries (in case a more general approach is required)

```
import pandas as pd
import staircase as sc

def create_union_stepfunction(dframe):
   return sc.Stairs(dframe, "contact_start", "contact_finish").make_boolean()

step_functions = df.groupby("name").apply(create_union_stepfunction)
```

This gives you a series called `step_functions`, indexed by planet name, and the values are `staircase.Stairs` objects which represent step functions.

```
name
Mars     <staircase.Stairs, id=1956311648200>
Venus    <staircase.Stairs, id=1956311120648>
dtype: object
```

These step functions have value 1 during contact, and 0 otherwise.  We can then slice the step functions up with bins and calculate the integral, to get the total time per bin that contact was made.  For daily bins use

```
def calc_seconds_per_bin(sf, bins):
    return sf.slice(bins).integral()/pd.Timedelta("1 second")


step_functions.apply(calc_seconds_per_bin, pd.date_range("2021-9-27", "2021-9-29"))
```

You'll get a `pandas.DataFrame`

```
        [2021-09-27, 2021-09-28)    [2021-09-28, 2021-09-29)
name        
Mars                        60.0                         0.0
Venus                      420.0                         0.0
```

**note:** I am the creator of staircase. Please feel free to reach out with feedback or questions if you have any.